# What is the "untagged" tag?

Tags: support, faq, tags

I see there are some questions tagged [untagged](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/untagged).

What does the tag mean?
What should I do when I find questions tagged with that tag?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### What does the tag mean?

[untagged](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/untagged) is a tag that is added to a question for which the existing tags have been removed. This happens when a question is migrated from another site: Every tag not defined from the site receiving the question is removed; if the question is left with zero tag, [untagged](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/untagged) is added to the question since each question needs at least a tag. (Synonyms are also checked; if the tag used from the origin site is a synonym in the receiving site, the tag will not be removed from the question, but replaced from the master tag.)

[untagged](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/untagged) cannot be manually added to questions. Any edit adding it will report the following error:

> The 'untagged' tag is not allowed.
> This is a special tag that is designed to be used only by the system for questions that have had all of their other tags removed. Please use a real tag instead.

#### What should I do when I find questions tagged with this tag?

[untagged](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/untagged) is a temporary tag that needs to be replaced with one or more tags defined in *Drupal Answers*. Check the question (including the question in the original site), and see which of the tags *Drupal Answers* uses applies to the question; the version tag about the Drupal version probably needs to be added, since tags matching ^drupal-?\d+.*$ are automatically removed when the question is migrated to *Drupal Answers*.