# Are tags automatically removed?

Tags: support, faq, tags

I noticed that one of the tags I used in my question has been removed. Are there cases where tags automatically removed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tags that are not used from any question are deleted every 24 hours from a [background process](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/40724/what-currently-happens-to-zombie-tags).

Tags that are used from a single question, and that have been created more than 6 months ago are automatically removed. When this happens, and the question used only a tag, the removed tag is replaced from [untagged](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/untagged). See [What is the "untagged" tag?](https://drupal.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/845/what-is-the-untagged-tag) for more information.

#### Reference

- [This answer on Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/48418/140449)